# How to detect data from multiple buttons in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, detection

I am quite new at developing html files and i came across 1 problem. Lets say i have 6 pictures, that work as buttons(they open popups etc).
So my question is... How can i pass data from what img was pressed and display it in a label?

img button code looks like this:

```
<td width="33%"><a onClick='javascript:fg_popup_form("fg_formContainer","fg_form_InnerContainer","fg_backgroundpopup");'><img src="img/klumpanje.gif" width="202" height="77"></a></td>
```

label is in a separate file of popup, looks like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <label  for='message'>Izbira:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <input name="message" type="text" id="message" value="knof1" size="50" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

Ty for the answers.

Comment: If you add `this` into the arguments of the `fg_popup_form` you can then get the value of the image tag by using `this.childNodes[0]` and get things like `width`, `height`, `src`.

Comment: Why don't use `<img onclick="fg_popup_form(this)" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new function that calls the popup and sent argument by that function

```
<td width="33%"><a id="kl" onClick='test("1");'> <img src="img/klumpanje.gif" width="202" height="77"></a></td>
```

function:

```
function test(tmp){
    var elem = document.getElementById('message');  

    if( tmp == "1")
    {
        elem.value="Klumpanje";
    }...
    javascript:fg_popup_form("fg_formContainer","fg_form_InnerContainer","fg_backgroundpopup","kl");
  }
```

Finnaly got it working. TY all for the answers, much appreciated :).

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are handling the popups, you could change your link code to something similar:

```
<a href="image-page.php?button=1" target="_blank"><img (your image tag here) /></a>
```

Then use PHP or other server side code to handle the GET request.
This way will also allow users who don't have javascript to use the images as buttons.

Comment: the popups are the same from all links -> they only thing different from each is their choice of picture and that decision sends to mail but the popups remain the same.

Comment: ?button=1 won't change the page, but it will give the server a variable and you can use that variable to do anything you want. In PHP the variable would be $_GET['button'] and it would equal "1" as a string.

Answer (score -1):

Add the id attribute in your anchor tag like `id="someID"` and pass the `id` in your `fg_popup_form()` function.  e.g;

```
<td width="33%"><a id="someID" onClick='javascript:fg_popup_form("someID","fg_formContainer","fg_form_InnerContainer","fg_backgroundpopup");'><img src="img/klumpanje.gif" width="202" height="77"></a></td>
```

Your function code should be like this

```
function fg_popup_form(id,formContainer,innerContainer,backgroundPopup)
{
  if(id == "someID")
  {
    // do your work
  }
  else if(id == "someID2")
  {
    // do your work
  }
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't say anywhere that she wanted to use jquery.

Comment: They never said what information they needed to gather and it shouldn't matter.  If you use `this` in the function then regardless of what ID it is it will pass whatever information you request from it.

this.childNodes[0] gets the <img> tag within the <a> tag, then you can use this.childNodes[0].src and get the src of the image.. or width, height, etc.

Comment: i just wanna put some pre-defined text into forum that sends it to my mail. Ex.: you have to choose 3 fruits(apple, orange and blueberry) i click on orange and pops up asks you for name and last name, then all this wrapped up sends to my mail. I got it all worked up just the transfer i didnt know how to approach it...